# How do I make NestedScrollView and RecyclerView scroll together?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

So I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` as I want to make my entire fragment scrollable.

This is what the layout looks like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.Recipes">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/text_view_1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/text1"
                    android:textColorHint="#757575"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_1"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_1"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/submit"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColorHint="#757575"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_view" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_2"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/example_item" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see, I also have an `EditText`, `Button` and `TextView` inside my `NestedScrollView`. Those will be shown by default, but the `RecyclerView` will only be populated after a certain behaviour is met. When the `RecyclerView` is populated, it shows a scrollable list. I want the screen to scroll with the `EditText`, `Button` and `TextView`. That way, those three components aren't fixed on the screen and when the user scrolls down, the three components will move up and disappear until the user scrolls back up.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I had `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` for both the `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollView`. Once I removed that and added `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to the `RecyclerView`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to have a package that contains `RecyclerView`, `EditText`, `TextView` etc. that scroll with the site. But the `RecyclerView` is still scrollable for itself. I achieved that by changing some lines and put a very long dummy text at the end below the `RecyclerView`. The `TextView` stands out at the lower end. The behaviour is that you can scroll the whole page and if you scroll inside the `RecyclerView`, only the `RecyclerView` is scrolling. That's what I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="text1"
            android:textColorHint="#757575"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColorHint="#757575"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_view" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvAnimals"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_view_2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:id="@+id/textview_long"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvAnimals"/>
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In the picture I made 3 yellow dots that proof everything is scrollable:

[image: Result]

---

I think the main problem you had was defining some attributes in the wrong way and obviously you had no extended content at the end of the screen. So there was nothing to do for the NestedScrollView.

**Ergo:** Your screen was large enough for the content and Scrolling became superfluous.

Comment: So I wanted it to scroll all together, like the way usual way you would scroll through an app. I don't want it where if you scroll the `RecyclerView` it'll just scroll the `RecyclerView`. I want it so that even if you scroll the `RecyclerView`, it will also scroll through the other components, thus making them disappear off the screen.

Comment: I updated my code as I realized I didn't include the entire scope of the XML file.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, I'll provide the answer in a separate comment.

Comment: Alright. Glad to hear. Should I delete my answer? I guess you will upvote your own right? To be honest the question lead to a more complicated problem then your solution actually is. Cheers! :)

Comment: I suggest deleting your answer just so future viewers don't become more confused by the problem. But thank you for the help, very much appreciate it.